How to estimate required hardware and performance for a deployed Ollama model?
I'm trying to give a rough estimate for deploying and using an LLM through an Ollama container on an Azure instance. What are some ways I can:

Estimate the hardware requirements for the server? (restriction is that servers with GPUs are not an option unless I can make a pretty good case for it)
Benchmark the performance of the model? (requests/responses per minute, concurrency handling, etc...)

What I have found so far is that there is a recommendation for a memory size that is 20% more than the model size. So assuming the usage of a model like Llama3.3-70B from Ollama where this model's size is 43GB:
40 * 1.2 = 51.6GB

But I believe that article made the recommendation based on VRAM. Any way I can create an estimate for a CPU server?
